# split function deprecated

Tags: php, deprecated

I got a deprecated error in my php script

```
Deprecated: Function split() is deprecated in directory\filename on line 153
```

This is the error line

```
list($ns, $el) = split( ':', $element, 2);
```

How do I fix this? I'm running in PHP5.3.

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.split.php#refsect1-function.split-notes) for this function?

Comment: Use preg_split(). http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: Use `preg_split` like suggested if you want to split based on regular expressions. Use `explode` if you want to split based on a simple character. From your example there, I would say go with `explode`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged. You can use `preg_split` for example `preg_split("/[\s,]+/", "hypertext language, programming")`. Or you can use `array explode ( string $delimiter , string $string [, int $limit ] )` for example

> // Example 1
> $pizza  = "piece1 piece2 piece3 piece4 piece5 piece6";
>
> $pieces = explode(" ", $pizza);
>
> echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
>
> echo $pieces[1]; // piece2
>
> // Example 2
> $data = "foo:*:1023:1000::/home/foo:/bin/sh";
>
> list($user, $pass, $uid, $gid, $gecos, $home, $shell) = explode(":", $data);
>
> echo $user; // foo
> echo $pass; // *

Answer (score 1):

As of PHP 5.3, the entire REGEX extension is deprecated. Use either the PCRE extension, which has a function `preg_split` and will pretty much give you the same result.

Looking at your code snippet, you do not really need a regular expression to split that string, which is what the PCRE extension offers.

You can use the `explode` function instead, which will also give you the same result without the need of parsing and tokenizing a regular expression.